# Splash screen won't move on to next screen after user signup on react navigation 6

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-stack

My React Native 0.66.1 app (on Big Sur/iPhone simulator) has a `SplashScreen` for reading local data. After splash screen, navigation moves to `AppScreen` which decides which screen to show next. The app uses React Navigation 6.x for navigation.

```
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
```

In `AppScreen`, if the local data loaded in splash screen is valid and success, then it will show the `Home` screen, if not, then show 'Signup' screen to let user to signup. After user signs up, then navigation goes to splash screen again to read the local data. Here is view portion of `AppScreen.js`:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
const AStack = createStackNavigator();
......
return(isLogin ? (
    <propsContext.Provider value={propsVal}>
        <authContext.Provider value={authVal}>
            <stateContext.Provider value={stateVal}>
              <AStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <AStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{headerLeft:false}}/>.  //<<===Home Screen after splash screen when user signs up
       
                <AStack.Screen name="Verif1" component={Verif1} options={{title:'验证'}} />
                <AStack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} options={{title:'我贴吧', 
                                                                          headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#f4511e',},
                                                                          headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center' },
                                                                          headerTintColor: '#fff', 
                                                                          headerShown:true}} />
                <AStack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
                <AStack.Screen name="AppScreen" component={AppScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
              </AStack.Navigator>
            </stateContext.Provider>
        </authContext.Provider>
    </propsContext.Provider>
    
  ) : (
    <propsContext.Provider value={propsVal}>
        <authContext.Provider value={authVal}>
            <stateContext.Provider value={stateVal}>
              <AStack.Navigator initialRouteName="Signup">. //<<== Signup screen after splash screen if login failed
                <AStack.Screen name="Verif1" component={Verif1} options={{title:'验证'}} />
                <AStack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} options={{title:'我贴吧', 
                                                                          headerStyle: {backgroundColor: '#f4511e',},
                                                                          headerTitleStyle: { alignSelf: 'center' },
                                                                          headerTintColor: '#fff', 
                                                                          headerShown:true,
                                                                          headerLeft:()=>null
                                                                          }} />
                <AStack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
                <AStack.Screen name="AppScreen" component={AppScreen} options={{headerShown:false}} />
                <AStack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{headerLeft:false}}/>
    ...               
              </AStack.Navigator>
            </stateContext.Provider>
        </authContext.Provider>
    </propsContext.Provider>
```

However the splash screen won't move to `Home` after user signs up with valid local data and `success:true`. Here is the screen route:

```
 App => Splash screen => Signup screen (2 screens here)=> Splash screen => Home Screen (didn't happen. Stuck at Splash screen)
```

The problem only happens recently and I am not aware of navigation being changed. What can causes `react navigation` holding on with splash screen and not move to `Home` screen?

Comment: problem solved by use `navigation.push` in place of `navigation.navigate` when routing back to `SplashScreen`. It is routing to splash screen the 2nd time and require a little `push` I guess.